# Vue broadcast event to multiple components

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a fairly simple component based question.

If I had 5 components and I click open on one, how can I tell the other 4 that they need to be closed?

To begin with I have put

```
this.$emit('open');
```

on the **component**. Then on the **app** I have put

```
@open="closeOthers"
```

Then in the **app** I have the following:

```
'methods':{
  closeOthers : function($event){
    console.log($event);
  }
}
```

But I'm just logging `undefined`. How can I

1. make this not log `undefined`
2. update the props on all other components

#### [Full code and demo here >>>](https://codepen.io/EightArmsHQ/pen/cab97ebbf7ed319b1d77a9306f3ba482)

Comment: You can use an event bus: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Non-Parent-Child-Communication

Comment: Oh... I think actually that may be overkill, I can just go `this.$emit('open', this.question.id);` then in my app go for each question if its id *isn't* the question id, hide it.

Comment: If your 'multiple components' have the same parent, then you're right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**for 1st**. You should pass event throw functions. Like this

```
   'toggleSelect' : function(e){
      this.$emit('open', e);
      this.question.open = !this.question.open;
    },
```

after this. This code will work

```
'methods':{
  closeOthers : function($event){
    console.log($event);
  }
}
```

**for 2nd**. To control open state it is better to move open value to parent and pass it to child.
[Full code jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vjvMp/1557/)